# Using group by to return a row with max()

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, inner-join

I am trying to get the items that their item_id exists in an array (arr_items) and have the higher num.

```
player_id | item_id | num | unique_number
-----------------------------------------
10        |    1    |  1  |      1
10        |    1    |  11 |      2
10        |    1    |  93 |      3
10        |    2    |  24 |      4
10        |    2    |  40 |      5
```

The expected result is to get the item_id 1 with num 93, and item_id 2 with num 40.

The below query returns no results. If I remove the `max` in the num, it works but doesn't return the item_id with the highest num. Suppose `arr_items = [1,2]`

```
SELECT a.player_id, a.item_id, a.num, a.unique_number
FROM my_table a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT player_id, item_id, max(num) AS max_num, unique_number
        FROM my_table
        WHERE
        player_id = 10
        AND item_id IN (arr_items)
        GROUP BY item_id
    ) b ON a.item_id = b.item_id AND
           a.player_id = b.player_id AND
           a.num = b.max_num AND
           a.unique_number = b.unique_number
;
```

**Edit:** 
The above query works fine if I remove the `unique_number` from the ON clause but I don't quite understand why. I also noticed, that if I have unique item_ids, then it works with the unique_number field in the on clause.

Meaning if my table was like the below, it would work. (the item_id values changed)

```
player_id | item_id | num | unique_number
-----------------------------------------
10        |    0    |  1  |      1
10        |    1    |  11 |      2
10        |    2    |  93 |      3
10        |    3    |  24 |      4
10        |    4    |  40 |      5
```

Comment: with the sample data, your query seems to be working. Are we missing something?

Comment: Hmm indeed. All I omitted was a unique number each item_id had, without it, it seems to working perfectly. I'll edit the question. Though I don't understand why it doesn't work with it.

Comment: @JohnJames "I don't quite understand why".  Because you don't write query properly.  In your inner loop, your `GROUP BY` is not even valid.  You have `player_id`, `item_id`, `unique_number` in `SELECT`, but not in `GROUP BY`.  It doesn't make sense.  From your example, for `player_id = 10`, which `item_id` will get picked up if it's not in `GROUP BY`?  Your query won't even run in any other dbms, except for maybe `MYSql`.

Comment: @JohnJames If you write a proper query, you'll know why including `unique_number` won't work.

Comment: @Eric so basically you are saying I should change `GROUP BY item_id` to `GROUP BY item_id, player_id, unique_number` ?

Comment: @JohnJames Yes you should group all the non-aggregated columns.  `GROUP BY player_id, item_id, unique_number`.  From here you will know why including `unique_number` won't work, because it's unique for each row, so your grouping will produce one row for each row.

Comment: Excellent, got it thanks :)

Comment: Mmmm, the real problem here is that MySQL, by default, allows `bad/non-standard` syntax for `group by` and you have adopted that as your expectation of how grouping should work. "Normally" group by syntax requires listing all non-aggregating columns. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 1):

MySQL provides a non-standard way of using group by which has regrettably "taught" many people to believe grouping is as simple as falling off a log, but yet somehow it could correctly guess/interpret the balance of the needed logic. The truth is that while grouping is quite easy, the weird non-standard syntax MySQL allows isn't always right (the result are an "approximation") and does not always guess correctly.

Your existing query can easily be modified to achieve what you need, but note that you really should always specify every non-aggregating column in the group by clause.

```
SELECT a.player_id, a.item_id, a.num, a.unique_number
FROM my_table a
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT player_id, item_id, max(num) max_num
        FROM my_table
        GROUP BY player_id, item_id
    ) b ON a.item_id = b.item_id 
       AND a.player_id = b.player_id 
       AND a.num = b.max_num
;
```

In the future, when MySQL does implement window functions, you will be able to use `row_number()` to achieve what you want and it will be a little more efficient as well:

```
select * 
from (
     select *
         , row_number() over(partition by player_id, item_id
                             order by num DESC) as rn
     from my_table
     ) d
where rn = 1
```

nb: This second query will always only return one row per `player_id, item_id` but the first query above could return more than one row IF num = max(num) is repeated per `player_id, item_id`